# Finding limit of $a_n=\left(\frac{999}{1000}+\frac{n^{(1000^{999})}}{\left(\frac{1000}{999}\right)^n}\right)^n,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to approach finding limit of $a_n$ sequence. At first glance it would seem to be 0, since denominators of both terms outgrow numerators, but could it potentially be transformed to $(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n$ form and have more interesting limit?
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=\left(\frac{999}{1000}+\frac{n^{(1000^{999})}}{\left(\frac{1000}{999}\right)^n}\right)^n, n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Where would be mistake in train of thought?:
$$a_n = \left( \frac{999}{1000}\cdot \left ( 1 + \frac{n^{\left(1000^{999}\right)}}{\left ( \frac{1000}{999}\right )^{n-1}} \right )\right)^n
=\left( \frac{999}{1000} \right)^n \cdot\left ( 1 + \frac{n^{\left(1000^{999}\right)}}{\left ( \frac{1000}{999}\right )^{n-1}} \right )^n
$$
$$a_n = b_n \cdot c_n, \quad \text{where} \quad b_n  =\left ( \frac{999}{1000} \right)^n, \quad
c_n = \left( 1 + \frac{n^{\left(1000^{999}\right)}}{\left ( \frac{1000}{999}\right )^{n-1}}\right)^n $$
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{999}{1000} \right)^n=0$$
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}c_n  = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{\left(\frac{1000}{999}\right)^{(1-n)}\cdot n^{998999}}{n}\right)^n = $$
$$ = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left( \left( 1 + \frac{\left(\frac{1000}{999}\right)^{(1-n)}\cdot n^{998999}}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{\left(\frac{1000}{999}\right)^{(1-n)}\cdot n^{998999}}}\right)^{\left(\frac{1000}{999}\right)^{(1-n)}\cdot n^{998999}}$$
$$
= e^{\left(\frac{1000}{999}\right)^{(1-n)}\cdot n^{998999}}
= c \neq \infty
$$
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(b_n\cdot c_n) = b \cdot c= 0 \cdot c = 0
$$

Comment: it seems to me that it is indeed zero, becasue for large $n$, $(1000/999)^n$ grows significantly faster than $n^k$ for a constant $k$. This is probably what the exercise wants to demonstrate.

Comment: $\lim_n a_n = \lim_n e^{\ln a_n} = e^{\lim_n \ln a_n}$.

Comment: Write $a=999/1000,b=1/a,c=1000^{999}$ so that $a, b, c$ are positive with $a<1<b$. Now your sequence is $(a+n^c/b^n) ^n$ with base tending to $a<1$. Compare this with $k^n\to 0$ if $0<k<1$.